# How to fetch unmatching records from two SQL tables?

Tags: sql

I want to fetch the unmatching records from two table in SQL, the table structure is as follows:

Table1

```
Id      Name
1       Prashant
2       Ravi
3       Gaurav
5       Naween
7       Sachin
```

Table2

```
Id      Name
1       Prashant
2       Ravi
4       Alok
6       Raja
```

The output I want is

```
Id      Name
3       Gaurav
4       Alok
5       Naween
6       Raja
7       Sachin
```

What will be the query to fetch the required output in SQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think joeslice's answer will only give half the results.  You need to union the other table.  Alternatively, you could do a full outer join.

```
select a.Id, a.Name from Table1 a left outer join Table2 b on a.Name = b.Name where b.Id is null
UNION ALL
select a.Id, a.Name from Table2 a left outer join Table1 b on a.Name = b.Name where b.Id is null
```

Comment: I guess that it is good enough to join on ID column instead of NAME

Answer (score 5):

```
create table #t1 (Id int, name varchar(50)) 
create table #t2 (Id int, name varchar(50)) 

insert #t1 values (1,       'Prashant')
insert #t1 values (2,      'Ravi')
insert #t1 values (3,       'Gaurav')
insert #t1 values (5,       'Naween')
insert #t1 values (7,       'Sachin')

insert #t2 values (1,       'Prashant')
insert #t2 values (2,       'Ravi')
insert #t2 values (4,       'Alok')
insert #t2 values (6,       'Raja')

select isnull(#t1.id, #t2.id), isnull(#t1.name,#t2.name)  from #t1 
full outer join #t2 on #t1.id = #t2.id
where #t2.Id is null or #t1.id is null
```

results:

```
3   Gaurav
5   Naween
7   Sachin
4   Alok
6   Raja
```

Comment: +1 good trick with "isnull" I had to use Union All to accomplish this!

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Id, Name
from Table1
where Id not in (select Id from Table2)
UNION 
Select Id, Name
from Table2
where Id not in (select Id from Table1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You actually CAN do it with one query:

```
SELECT      COALESCE(table1.ID, table2.ID) AS ID,
            COALESCE(table1.Name, table2.Name) AS Name
FROM        table1
FULL JOIN   table2
        ON  table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE       table1.ID IS NULL OR table2.ID IS NULL
```

will result in:

```
ID          Name
----------- --------
3           Gaurav
5           Naween
7           Sachin
6           Raja
4           Alok
```

Comment: similar answer to mine :p but i managed to squeeze in the isnull as well :p

Comment: @Sam: +1: I prefer COALESCE though :)

Comment: +1 COALESCE is the true ANSI SQL standard, ISNULL only works on some DBs (like SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM Table1
 MINUS
  SELECT * FROM Table2
)
UNION
(
  SELECT * FROM Table2
 MINUS
  SELECT * FROM Table1
)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM
 Table1 a 
FULL OUTER JOIN
 Table2 b 
ON
 a.ID=b.ID AND a.Name=b.NAME
WHERE
 a.ID IS NULL OR b.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` does not work in MySQL. But who care, MySQL sucks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    select t.ID, t.Name from Table1 t
    left outer join Table2 tt
    ON tt.name = t.name
    where tt.id is null

    union all

    select t.ID, t.Name from Table2 t
    left outer join Table1 tt
    ON tt.name = t.name
    where tt.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.Id, a.Name 
from Table1 a 
left outer join Table2 b 
on a.Name = b.Name 
where b.Id is null
```

EDIT:  My answer is wrong....  it will give you only the results from Table1 that are not found in Table2.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This query will only give the records from table1 that are not in table2. The question asks for the unmatched records in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get the unmatched records from both tables, I think that you will need two queries (one for each table) which will be unioned together:

```
(SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name 
 FROM Table1 as t1 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name 
 WHERE t2.Id is null)
UNION
(SELECT t2.Id, t2.Name 
 FROM Table2 as t2 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 as t1 on t2.Name = t1.Name 
 WHERE t1.Id is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALSCE(t1.name, t2.name) AS "name"
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.name IS NULL
OR t2.name IS NULL;
```

Comment: first we have join the tables using  full outer join so it is combination of left outer join and right outer join then we have given two null values from either side so there will not be any column who have both null values. So it will return the values which are not in another table.

Comment: yes.. output is like  null+table2 value i.e. table2 value 
or table1 value + null i.e. table1 value which works..

Comment: you can use set operator for this also. I was solving this query using joins only. If want to solve it by using SETS then it will be like this..
SELECT coalesce(t1.name, t2.name)
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
MINUS 
SELECT coalesce(t1.name, t2.name)
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name)
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
MINUS 
SELECT coalesce(t1.name, t2.name)
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;

Answer (score 0):

First of all union both the tables:

```
with data as
(
select * from t1
union
select * from t2)
select * from data
```

interim temporary output:

```
    Id  name
1   1   Prashant
2   2   Ravi
3   3   Gaurav
4   4   Alok
5   5   Naween
6   6   Raja
7   7   Sachin
```

Now from data remove the common ids using inner join:
**THE SOLUTION**

```
with data as
    (
    select * from t1
    union
    select * from t2)
    select * from data 
    where id not in (select t1.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id);
```

FINAL OUTPUT:

```
    Id  name
1   3   Gaurav
2   4   Alok
3   5   Naween
4   6   Raja
5   7   Sachin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.common_key = table2.common_key
WHERE table2.common_key IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT table2.*
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.common_key = table2.common_key
WHERE table1.common_key IS NULL;
```